# Compilation of erld on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: services, make, compiling

I am compiling `erld`, a program to run Erlang programs as a UNIX daemon, see

https://github.com/ShoreTel-Inc/erld/wiki

The make instructions which I followed are here:

https://github.com/ShoreTel-Inc/erld/blob/master/README

In the middle of the `make` step there is an error:

```
In file included from slay.c:25:0:
debug.h:41:6: warning: conflicting types for built-in 
  function ‘log’ [enabled by default]
slay.c:29:45: fatal error: proc/readproc.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [erld-slay.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ad/erld/c_src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

This is ubuntu 12.04 server 64:

```
$ uname -a
Linux lfe1 3.2.0-26-virtual #41-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 18:08:54 UTC 2012 
  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

I was not able to add the tag "erlang" to this question. Maybe someone with more points can do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install [libproc-dev](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/libproc-dev) [image: Install libproc-dev]

or run `sudo apt-get install libproc-dev`

Comment: on ubuntu 14.04 ´sudo apt-get install libprocps3-dev´

Answer (score 0):

For AMD GPUs use the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install libprocps4-dev
```

to install libproc.

Installing libproc-dev doesn't work now